dayjs.toString() prints wrong time
import dayjs from "dayjs";

console.log(dayjs().startOf('day').format())  // 2024-06-21T00:00:00+08:00
console.log(dayjs().startOf('day').toString()) // Thu, 20 Jun 2024 16:00:00 GMT

The time in format() is correct.
The time printed by toString() is totally wrong.
why?

Actually, they are the same time.
The toString() function of dayjs converts date to Greenwich Mean Time.
Your first datetime is on GMT/UTC +08:00, but second one is on GMT +00:00.
Thus, the difference of them is 8 hrs.
Hope this can be helpful.

Why are the two behaviors different? I didn't find any explanation about this difference in the official documentation.

I'm not sure why dayjs developer didn't add detail, but toString() method is same as toUTCString() which is provided by default javascript library.
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/8d5d521602a2ee80a5ae13cb916b8d0e6bb287a6/src/index.js#L427
You can check code here. @SageJustus
